# Recursive macro in Common Lisp

Tags: recursion, macros, lisp, common-lisp

I have to write recursive macro in Common Lisp.

I have a function that searches maximal element in list. For example it returns 
`45` for list `(2 4 6 42 5 45 3)`. Now I'm about to convert it to recursive macro.

Here is my code:

```
(defmacro mymax (values)                     
    (cond 
        ((= (length values) 1) `(write (car ,values)))
        ((> (car values) (cadr values)) (mymax (list (car values) (cddr values))))    
        (t (mymax (cdr values)))
    )
)
```

It doesn't work. Compilation error: "LIST is not a real number". I've tried different combinations of '`' and ',' - with no result. How to correct my code so the result of a macro will be a number?

Macro invocation:
`(write (mymax (list 3 5 6 7 8)))`

or

`(write (mymax (cons 3 5 6 7 8)))`

or

`(write (mymax '(3 5 6 7 8)))`

All of this invocations ends with the same result.

Comment: why does it have to be a macro? is this a h/w assignment? how do you invoke your macro?

Comment: that makes little sense...

Comment: It's a requirement for a project. Recursive function is a simple task, so it needs to be a macro. I've added invocation to main post.

Comment: It could be a macro e.g. that sums from `1 to n` (where `n` is parameter) - if it is simpler one.

Comment: A macro takes code and generates code. What code should it generate?

Comment: Where does the word 'LISP' comes from in the error message? It's neither in your code nor in the example form.

Comment: in your example you have the word 'list'. What is the maximum of 'list' and 3?

Comment: Macro should generate just a number - maximal element in list.
@RainerJoswig my mistake, it should be 'LIST'.

Comment: debug the macro by adding print statements to the macro and use `macroexpand-1` to see the generated code.

Comment: how should it generate a maximum number from a list `(list 1 2 3)` ? `list` is not a number.

Comment: List constructs a list from following objects. I can invoke by `(write (mymax '(3 5 6 7 8)))` and a result is the same.

Comment: `'(3 5 6 7 8)` is really `(quote (3 5 6 7 8))`. How should the macro compute the maximum of the symbol `quote` and the list `(3 5 6 7 8)` ??

Comment: You're not calling `list`.

Comment: I tried code from this site [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html).

Comment: How should `(mymax a)` work? How should the macro compute the maximum of the symbol `a`. `a` is not a list of numbers. Remember, macros take source code, here `a`, not evaluated arguments.

Comment: The site link is about Emacs Lisp, not Common Lisp. `cons` does only take two arguments. So `(cons 3 5 6 7 8)` can't work. Please don't post code you have not tried to run. If you had tried it, you would have seen the error in the call to `cons`.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Okay, is it about placing a backquote (`) before some part of code in a macro? I've added backquotes befrore conditions and 'then code' and it works but it prints first number from a sequence, not a highest one. Unfortunately I'm a newbie in common lisp (I've started 3 days ago) so I don't know how to debug using GNU CLISP in Windows.

Comment: Debug the macro by using print statements. `values` is already wrong as a variable name. Macros don`t take values as arguments. They take code. Source code. Macros transform source code to source code. Think about that. Source code! Not data. Functions take data as arguments. Macros get source code. That's why they are called Macros and not Functions. What does it then mean to rewrite a function as a macro? Does that make sense? What source code would the macro get and what would it generate. It has nothing to do with backquotes. You need to have an idea what you want to achieve and how.

Comment: I honestly think it's a bit early to start writing macros after three days of Lisp, especially if you have been exposed to one of the Lesser Languages with "macros", like C. And this particular function is very pointless to make a macro of.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, I understand all of them. I agree it's too early but unfortunately I have to do this and I don't have much time. I need some recursive macro it hasn't be this one. I'll think about another one and I will try to debug them as you described. For now let's close this post. Thanks again.

Comment: And of course I am "c" guy so it's not obvious how macro works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a macro version of the function `MAX`, which does something useful when every argument is a number:

```
(defmacro mymax (&rest numbers)
  (flet ((all-number-list-p (list)                     ; local function
           (and (listp list)                           ; it's a list
                (numberp (first list))                 ; the first number exists
                (every #'numberp list))))              ; everything is a number
    (if (all-number-list-p numbers)                    ; only numbers? 
        (cond ((null (rest numbers)) (first numbers))  ; one number
              ((> (first numbers) (second numbers))    : first is greater
               `(mymax ,@(cons (first numbers)         ; get rid of the second
                               (cddr numbers))))
              (t                                       ; second is greater
               `(mymax ,@(rest numbers))))             ; get rid of the first
      `(max ,@numbers))))                              ; fallback, use MAX
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 23 > (macroexpand-1 '(mymax 4 1 3 2))
(MYMAX 4 3 2)
T

CL-USER 24 > (macroexpand-1 '(mymax 4 3 2))
(MYMAX 4 2)
T

CL-USER 25 > (macroexpand-1 '(mymax 4 2))
(MYMAX 4)
T

CL-USER 26 > (macroexpand-1 '(mymax 4))
4
T

CL-USER 27 > (mymax 4 1 3 2)
4
```

Note that it just uses `MAX` when not every argument is a number:

```
CL-USER 28 > (macroexpand-1 '(mymax a b 8 d))
(MAX A B 8 D)
```

Comment: Wouldn't  `(and (consp list) (every #'numberp list))` be sufficient?

Comment: @coredump: yes, I wanted it to be more explicit, though. To make it clear that at least one number is needed. This is implicitly in your condition contained.

Comment: I find `(numberp (first list))` more indirect because it can be false either if there is no first element or because the first is not a number, whereas `cons` seems more explicit to me. I guess it is a matter of taste.

Comment: @coredump: that's exactly what I wanted to do: talk about the content, not the representation as linked cells.

Comment: Wow, that's very useful, thanks! It gives me different point of view on macros in Lisp. However macro defined like this `(
 defmacro Power (values)
 \`(
  if (= (second ,values) 0) 1 
  (
   * (first ,values) (Power (list (first ,values) (- (second ,values) 1)))
  )
 )
)` works perfectly when running from cmd by typing `clisp name.lisp`. When compiling with clisp and then running `name.fas` file it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`(a b c)`

- If you *read* at the above form, it is a list of 3 symbols.
- When you *evaluate* it, if `a` is not bound to a macro, then the form is a function call to *a* where *b* and *c* are evaluated.

`'(a b c)`, a.k.a. `(quote (a b c))`

- If you *read* this one, you have a list of two elements, first `quote` and then a list of 3 symbols.
- If you *evaluate* the form, the returned value is a list of 3 symbols: `(a b c)`

Macros are given unevaluated source code as *read* by the Lisp reader.

In `(mymax '(1 2 3))`, `'(1 2 3)` is the unevaluated form `(quote (1 2 3))`. In `(mymax (list 1 2 3))`, the unevaluated argument has 4 elements, the first one being a symbol. What should you give the macro so that it has the following list `(1 2 3)`?

When in doubt, macroexpand.